# Inquiry about using pcloud API using access token

Tags: access-token, pcloud

I'm currently studying the `pCloud` API and have a couple of specific questions regarding its usage:

Q1.

Use the userinfo API with your access token and you'll get an instant response.

```
import requests

account_url = "https://api.pcloud.com/userinfo"

access_token ="ACCESS TOKEN"

response = requests.get(account_url, headers={
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
})`your text`

account_info = response.json()
print(account_info)
```

However, if you use `listtokens` API instead of userinfo API, you will receive `{'result': 1000, 'error': 'Log in required.'} response.`

Is there a way to use the `listtokens` API using an access token?

I know that I can use authentication token as below.
([https://api.pcloud.com/listtokens?auth={Authentication](https://api.pcloud.com/listtokens?auth=%7BAuthentication) token})

I contacted the `pcloud` support team and was told to only look at docs.pcloud.com

Or is there a way to obtain an authentication token using an access token?
(other than using passworddigest)

Get solutions and USE API